# How to retrieve data from a iframe on a HTTPS secured site with a login

Tags: python, authentication, https, urllib2

I have been trying to make a script, that will enable me to grab my grades from our online internal webpage.

The page i want to retrieve data from is https://sb.stads.ku.dk/SB_PSTA/sb/resultater/studresultater.jsp

I have tried doing this in Python. But whenever i get logged in, i don't know how to get to this page in the script. Simply accessing the page is not enough. It seems as if i get redirected after logging in.

Here is what i have so far.

```
import urllib2

theurl = 'https://intranet.ku.dk/Selvbetjening/Sider/default.aspx'
username = 'MYUSERNAME'
password = 'MYPASSWORD'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)

authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(theurl)

for elm in pagehandle: 
    print elm
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the response status is 301 or 302, which means a redirection, we'll get the redirected url in 'location' parameter. Then using that url, you need to make the request again. Remember, this url will expect the user to be logged in, so you need to pass on all the cookies too.

What you are essentially doing is scraping this website to retrieve data from it. You need to take of the following things:

1. Do the same the steps you want to follow in a browser. Like opening the web page, posting the form and clicking on links etc.
2. Use a development tool on browser(Eg- firebug for Firefox browser) and replicate the same request each time through the code.
3. Any cookies which come in web page response, is automatically saved by the browser and is sent along with the next request. Hence we need to do the same thing here. Every time we get a response, save the cookies in a variable and send it with the request headers of the next request.
4. If there is any redirect response, then make another request to the redirected url. Basically do the same thing which the browser would've done.

This is code piece using httplib.

```
class scraper():
    def somefunc(self):
        self.host = "intranet.ku.dk"
        self.url = "https://intranet.ku.dk/Selvbetjening/Sider/default.aspx"
        self.data = urllib.urlencode(postDataDict)
        self.headers = {   #You can fill these values by looking into what the browser sends.
            'Accept': 'text/html; */*',
            'Accept-Language': '',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        response = makeRequest(host,url,data)
        if (response.status == 302):
            url = '/'+response.getheader("Location").split('/')[3]
            response = makeRequest(host,url,{})

    def makeRequest(self,host,url,data):
        cookies = ''
        for key in self.cookies:
            cookies = cookies + key + '=' + self.cookies[key] + '; '
        self.headers['Cookie'] = cookies
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
        conn.request("POST", url, data, self.headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        self.saveCookies(response.getheader("Set-Cookie"))
        responseVal = response.read()
        conn.close()
        self.headers['Referer'] = fullUrl #setting header for next request
        return response

    def saveCookies(self,cookies):
        if cookies is not None:
            values = cookies.split()
            for value in values:
                parts = value.split('=')
                if(len(parts) > 1):
                    if((parts[0] != 'expires') and (parts[0] != 'Max-Age') and (parts[0] != 'Path') and (parts[0] != 'path') and (parts[0] != 'Domain')):
                        self.cookies[parts[0]] = parts[1].rstrip(';')
```

PS: I have modified my specific code to make it general, hence please check for any errors.

Comment: @Jonas Lomholdt Kindly close the question by [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it worked for you.